# facebook ads stats connections

Tags: facebook, ads

Below is an example response i am getting for stats on an adgroup.

The "connections" returns 12 and the "actions" : null
How do i get to the break down of the connection? (pagelike/app installs/event responses)

Thank you!

```
{
  "id": "XXXXX", 
  "impressions": "789862", 
  "clicks": "292", 
  "spent": "3019", 
  "social_impressions": "109327", 
  "social_clicks": "26", 
  "social_spent": "235", 
  "unique_impressions": 295055, 
  "social_unique_impressions": 18819, 
  "unique_clicks": 287, 
  "social_unique_clicks": 25, 
  "actions": null, 
  "connections": 12, 
  "adgroup_id": XXX, 
  "campaign_id": XXX, 
  "start_time": "2011-08-21T00:00:00+0000", 
  "end_time": "2011-08-22T00:00:00+0000", 
  "newsfeed_position": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ad Statistics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/) and [Conversion Statistics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversionstatistics/) documentation - you're probably looking for `/conversions` instead of `/stats`

Sample query: `/<CAMPAIGN ID>/conversions/0/1354207892`
sample response is:

```
{
  "campaign_id": <CAMPAIGN ID>, 
  "values": [
    {
      "start_time": 0, 
      "end_time": 1354233600, 
      "conversions": [
        {
          "action_type": "like", 
          "object_id": <PAGE ID>, 
          "post_click_1d": 345, 
          "post_click_7d": 349, 
          "post_click_28d": 351, 
          "post_imp_1d": 53, 
          "post_imp_7d": 89, 
          "post_imp_28d": 104
        }, 
        {
          "action_type": "link_click", 
          "object_id": <PAGE ID>, 
          "post_click_1d": 893, 
          "post_click_7d": 904, 
          "post_click_28d": 938, 
          "post_imp_1d": 120, 
          "post_imp_7d": 185, 
          "post_imp_28d": 235
        }, 

      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: hi, did you ever get around to find the solution for this? even with both API i don't see what should be summed for "actions" and what should be summed for "pagelikes/eventresponse/etc"

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you will get a non-null result for the actions field of a stats query if you don't specify a start_time.